# Configuration required to enable mongodb batch in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring boot MongoTemplate. I am using `insert(Collection, EntityClass)` method to insert a list of data as a single batch.

**Questions:**

1. Do I have to do any other configuration explicitly to enable batch?
2. How can I verify if the batch is working or not?
3. Is `insert(Collection, EntityClass)` and BulkOperation same?

Comment: do you know this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#insert-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Class-

Comment: yes i am talking about same `insert` method, my question what is the difference this method and using bulk write api. and is there a way we can verify batch insert is happening?